# Bash "if" condition

Tags: bash

Ubuntu 16.04...I have a script to check external IP address:

```
GETIPADDR=`wget -q -O - checkip.dyndns.org|sed -e 's/.*Current IP Address: //' -e 's/<.*$//'`
...

if [ $GETIPADDR = "" ]; then
```

The GETIPADDR line works under normal conditions, and $GETIPADDR will have the string value of the external IPv4 address.  When external connectivity is lacking or some other problem occurs with the wget, an echo of $GETIPADDR shows it has no content, but the if does not return a true condition (the "then" does not execute).

Can someone educate me as to why?  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You have to quote the expansion of `$GETIPADDR`; otherwise, the empty string is removed from the command line before `[` runs, and you get a syntax error.

```
if [ "$GETIPADDR" = "" ]; then
```

Your code, if the variable is empty, is equivalent to

```
if [ = "" ]; then
```

not

```
if [ "" = "" ]; then
```

---

The preferred way to check for an empty string is to use the `-z` operator:

```
if [ -z "$GETIPADDR" ]; then
```

Comment: Please also include the option of using `-z` for empty check, It does not directly answer the question, but it is a good advice